# JAVASCRIPT removeRow() function

Tags: removechild, appendchild

i would like to know the syntax for removing a row which was added by appendchild.

There is also a removechild, but I am not sure how to operate.

```
<input type="button" id='submitlink' value="ADD_AGENDA" onClick="generateRowAgenda()" name="AGENDA"/>
<input type="button" id='submitlink' value="" onClick="removeRow()" name="AGENDA"/>

<script language="">
function generateRowAgenda() {

    var temp ="<p><input type='text' class='textinputagenda' name='MM_AGENDA[]'></p>";
    var newdiv = document.createElement('AGENDA');
    newdiv.innerHTML = temp;
    var yourDiv = document.getElementById('AGENDA');
    yourDiv.appendChild(newdiv);
}

function removeRow(){
  yourDiv.appendChild.deleteRow(newdiv);
}



</script>

<br>
<div id="AGENDA" align="center"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
function removeRow(element){
   element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
removeRow(newDiv);
```

That is, the `removeChild` method actually belongs to the element's **parent**, so you need to reference the parent first (by using `parentNode`) and then call the method `removeChild` over the `newDiv` element.

Also, you have two elements with the same id: `submitlink`. And that is not good.

If you rename your element, you could add a listener that call the `removeRow` function.

`<input type="button" id='doremove' value="" onClick="removeRow()" name="AGENDA"/>`

(Now the `id` is `doremove`)

Now do something like this to make the `removeRow` function to be executed on click:

```
document.getElementById('doremove').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    removeRow(newDiv);
});
```

Here is an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5TmQC/

You'll notice that remove only works with one agenda item. You want to work with several agendas?

Try this then: http://jsfiddle.net/5TmQC/1/

Almost same code, but this one can delete several, in order by using `pop()`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! This was exactly what i was looking for. And thanks for the hint to order by pop(). Appologize, for the rubish ID on the removeRow button, it happens sometimes by copy and paste.

Comment: @Luca, I'm glad it was useful to you. If this answer was useful, please mark it as accepted.